# JWT authorization in microservices

Tags: spring, microservices

Suppose I have two services: `user-service` and `hospital-service`.

`user-service` deals with registration of new users, generates JWT access and refresh tokens, validates tokens and authorizes users by adding them to `SecurityContext`.

The `hospital-service` deals with working with patients and doctors in the database. A receptionist and a doctor have different access rights. For example, a doctor cannot add new doctors, while a receptionist can.

So there are two groups of users, *doctors* and *receptionist*, the assignment of these roles is also handled by `user-service`.

How to link these two services so that `hospital-service` knows which user is accessing it now and understands whether it is possible to give him certain data or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a confusing aspect about your question: If *user-service* and *hospital-service* are microservices, they will run in separate processes and cannot share a Spring `SecurityContext`. If they are Spring services in the same process, they can share the `SecurityContext` instance. But then there is no need for a JWT as JWTs are used for REST services.

In any case: *doctors* and *receptionist* are roles. Add the user's role to `SecurityContext` (Spring calls them *authorities*) or add them as a claim to the JWT.

In the code, Spring lets you declare that a method may only be executed if the user has a certain role. Or you can query the role to modify a database query.

**Update**

Given the clarification that the goal are microservices in separate processes:

The overall architecture will involve at least three components:

- *user-service*
- *hospital-service*
- client (accessing the APIs of *hospital-service*, likely providing the user interface for it)

*user-service* has the role of an identity and access management system (IAM). It should preferably implement the protocols and flows of OAuth 2.x or – even better – OpenID Connect. In OAuth terms, this component has the role of an *Identity Provider*. *user-service* authenticates the user and issues a JWT containing additional user information such as roles.

*hospital-service* will be a face-less service offering APIs. It can be accessed given a valid JWT issued by *user-service*. It either validates the JWT itself by checking the signature (most common solution) or contacts the *user-service* for validation (less common, slower solution). In OAuth terms, *hospital-service* is a resource server.

The client will need to first contact the *user-service* to get a JWT. With that JWT, it can then access the *hospital-service*.

If *user-service* implements the OpenID Connect protocol, implementing the security checks in *hospital-service* is basically a one-liner (see Spring documentation about [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html)). Spring will automatically populate the security context with all relevant information including roles.

For the implementation of *user-service*, there are two options:

- In most commercial environments, there is already an identity provider in place to authenticate users, e.g. ActiveDirectory in a Windows environment. Single sign-on is desired (instead of a separate user management with separate passwords). If so, it's better to hook into those for user administration. Most systems either support OAuth out-of-the-box, or there is a bridging solution available like Microsoft Entra ID (formerly Azure AD).
- If no integration with an existing identity provider is desired, then you want to look at [Spring Authorization Server](https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server), a framework for implementing an identity provider / authorization server.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how I can redesign it so that `hospital-service` can also add a user to its context. Maybe use Spring Cloud Gateway which will extract the username and role from the access token and pass it on to `hospital-service`. What are some ways to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you specify if you're implementing two microservices in separate processes or two Spring services in the same process?

Comment: I want to implement two microservices in separate processes